# How to add relative layout below parent linear layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I have this activity with linear layout(called myLayout) and in it there are two buttons. Then, I dynamically made array of textViews and added them below each other in a new relative layout(called relLayout). Now I want to put this relLayout **below** these two buttons in myLayout. But I don't know how, maybe with `myLayout.addView(relLayout, fparams);` but then I don't know how to define fparams..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-** First Let be a `LinearLayout` as the `Main Parent layout` suppose named as **L1**, with `Vertical orientation.`

**-** Then create a second `LinearLayout` names as **L2** as the `child to the parent` layout **L1**, with `Vertical orientation`

**-** Place the 2 `button` in this child `LinearLayout L2.`

**-** Set this `LinearLayout` L2 attribute named `Layout_weight as 1.`

**-** Now place the `RelativeLayout` below this LinearLayout L2, and then dynamically generate the `textView` here....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: actually i tried only to change the orientation of myLayout to "vertical" and it worked, but now i have another question:
i want to have textView and 3 radio buttons next to the textView all in one row, and then the same below and below for n times. how to do this, maybe with view group? sry for bothering...

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your whole layout page including the `myLayout` and `relLayout`, into another `RelativeLayout`.
Then you would specify to the `relLayout` to position below `myLayout` like this:

```
android:layout_below="@id/myLayout_ID"
```